# Sort Country picklist fetched using wire method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I have fetched country global picklist using wire method in Javascript. I need to put United states as the first value in the picklist. How should I sort the values written by wire method.

```
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$applicationMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId' ,
        fieldApiName: COUNTRY
    })
    wiredCountires({ data }) {
        this._countries = data?.values;
    }
```

getting response from wire method like below

```
224
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'Ukraine', validFor: Array(0), value: 'Ukraine'}
225
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'United Arab Emirates', validFor: Array(0), value: 'United Arab Emirates'}
226
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'United Kingdom', validFor: Array(0), value: 'United Kingdom'}
227
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'United States', validFor: Array(0), value: 'United States'}
228
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'Uruguay', validFor: Array(0), value: 'Uruguay'}
229
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'Uzbekistan', validFor: Array(0), value: 'Uzbekistan'}
230
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'Vanuatu', validFor: Array(0), value: 'Vanuatu'}
231
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of', validFor: Array(0), value: 'Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of'}
232
: 
{attributes: null, label: 'Vietnam', validFor: Array(0), value: 'Vietnam'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a full sort, just a splice and unshift will do:

```
this._countries = [...data.values]; // wire data is immutable, so copy
const usaIndex = this._countries.findIndex((option)=>option.label==='United States');
const usaOption = this._countries[usaIndex];
this._countries.splice(usaIndex, 1); // Remove from original location
this._countries.unshift(usaOption); // And add to beginning
```

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox it works!!

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple search for United States in the array and swap it to first place...
do your data operations in connected callback